# Autohotkey bind (CapsLock+D+J) to (Delete)

Tags: autohotkey

I'm trying to overload my keyboard.

CapsLock & J::Send {Left}
..is the left arrow, you can guess the other directions.

CapsLock & H::Send ^{Left}
..is jump word left.

I started adding a lot of extra and I am running out of keys, so I thought I would like to introduce extra modifiers like D could be de "Delete modifier". CapsLock+D+J would delete a char form the Left (like Backspace key), CapsLock+D+L would delete a char from the right (like Delete key).

Additionally, S would be my Speedy modifier like Ctrl, meaning "jump words". So CapsLock+S+D+J would delete a word to the left.

If I could only...
-bind to 3+ keys, that would solve it.
-bind to any keyup/down and process it in if-else blocks, that would solve it.

Ideas appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Three modifiers like `CapsLock & H & D` cannot be used.

You can use [GetKeyState](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/GetKeyState.htm) and combine it with hotkeys and if or switch statements to make any combination.

Comment: Why didn't you make this an official answer?

Comment: I new about GetKeyState but I forgot to state that in my question, and it is quite relevant so I accept your answer, although I also posted what really did it. Thank you though, Armin.

Answer (score 1):

The trick to catch any keyup/down event happens to be this:

```
*d::msgbox, d down
*d up::msgbox, d up
```

Note that "d down" fires many times until you release it. `*` stands for any modifier keys like shift/alt/ctrl/win (or nothing).

To handle anything I use sg. like this:

```
updateState(key, dir) {..}

*a::updateState("a", "down")
*a up::updateState("a", "up")
*b::updateState("b", "down")
*b up::updateState("b", "up")
*c::updateState("c", "down")
...
```

and I store all the key states I need in variables like `key_a`, `key_b`, `key_capslock`, ..

Also, the current event is in a variable like `a_down`, `a_up`, `b_down`, `b_up`, ..

Then I can use if-else statements like

```
if(key_capslock and key_d and key_f and j_down) {
    ; do whatever
}
```

No, I can't recognize any speed decrease while typing.

If the CapsLock is not pressed I use the following to "pass through" the normal keyboard functionality:

```
; DEFAULT keyboard
if(key_capslock = 0) {
    if(key_shift)
        shift := "+"
    if(key_ctrl)
        ctrl := "^"
    if(key_alt)
        alt := "!"

    if(dir="down") {
        event = {%key% down}
    }
    else {
        event = {%key% up}
    }

    SendInput, %shift%%ctrl%%alt%%event%
}
```

Edit: Note that some keys can not be detected at the same time, as (most?) keyboards have a matrix layout with horizontal and vertical wires. Once a key is pressed, 1 horizontal and 1 vertical wire is used, thus a next keypress/release sharing any of these wires can not be accurately detected. For that reason, I can't use S and JKL at the same time, hence I use F for FAAST instead of S for SPEEDY. :/